# Format Date to MM/DD/YYYY Using toLocaleString

Tags: javascript, webdriver-io

In JS, how can I get the date to format to MM/DD/YYYY?

```
new Date(Date.now() + (8 * 86400000)).toLocaleString().split(',')[0])
returns "12/1/2020"
```

How can I format it to "12/01/2020"?

```
fromDate:
(new Date(Date.now() + (1 * 86400000)).toLocaleString().split(',')[0]),
toDate:
(newDate(Date.now() + (8 * 86400000)).toLocaleString().split(',')[0])
```

I would like the fromDate and toDate to be:

If between 5:00 PM MST and Midnight: set `fromDate` to `tomorrow's` date , and `toDate` to `tomorrow's date + 7 days`

How can compare the currentTime to say if it is greater than 5 PM local time?

```
let currentTime = new Date().toLocaleTimeString('en-US', {
  hour: '2-digit',
  minute: '2-digit',
  second: '2-digit',
  hour12: false
});
```

Comment: look at using [Intl.DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat) - you'll want `en-us` locale, with 2 digit month and day, and numeric year

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the `options` argument in `.toLocaleString` to format your date as "MM/DD/YYYY"

```js
var currentDate = new Date(Date.now() + (8 * 86400000))
var newDateOptions = {
        year: "numeric",
        month: "2-digit",
        day: "2-digit"
}
var newDate = currentDate.toLocaleString("en-US", newDateOptions );

console.log(newDate)
```

A detailed post on how to use the arguments in `.toLocaleString` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString

Answer (score 0):

This from another post here.

```
var currentD = new Date();
var startHappyHourD = new Date();
startHappyHourD.setHours(17,30,0); // 5.30 pm
var endHappyHourD = new Date();
endHappyHourD.setHours(18,30,0); // 6.30 pm

console.log("happy hour?")
if(currentD >= startHappyHourD && currentD < endHappyHourD ){
    console.log("yes!");
}else{
    console.log("no, sorry! between 5.30pm and 6.30pm");
}
```